# how to return a dictionary from a function in cpp

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11

I have this code

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

int test(int x, int y){
   std::map<std::tuple<int, int>, std::string> test_1;
   std::tuple<int, int> test2;
   test2 = make_tuple(x,y);
   test_1.insert<std::pair<std::tuple<int, int>, std::string>(test2, "string");
   return test_1;
}
```

Error:

> 'return': cannot convert from 'std::mapstd::tuple<int,int,std::string,std::lessstd::tuple<int,int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int,int>,std::string>>>' to 'int'

Comment: `std::map<std::tuple<int, int>, std::string> test(int x, int y)`?

Comment: Aside: if you find yourself explicitly specifying the template parameters for function templates you call, you are probably doing something wrong. `test_1.emplace(test2, "string");` is much nicer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return `std::map<std::tuple<int, int>, std::string>` but you have written the return type as `int`.

```
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

std::map<std::tuple<int, int>, std::string> test(int x, int y){
   std::map<std::tuple<int, int>, std::string> test_1;
   std::tuple<int, int> test2;
   test2 = make_tuple(x,y);
   test_1.insert<std::pair<std::tuple<int, int>, std::string>(test2, "string");
   return test_1;
}
```